# How to get the Kifflom achievement

Tags: achievements, grand-theft-auto-v

I have tried google and could not find where to start it.

- Where do I find the path to enlightenment?
- What is it?
- How do I complete it?
- Is it online or single-player?

Answer (score 1):

This a offline mission series for Michael. Enter the Epsom site and complete the survey (it doesn't matter what you answer) and in a few minutes you receive an email from Epsom asking for a $500 donation. Donate and wait until a question mark (**?**) appears in Raton Canyon.

Once you go to the Raton Canyon and talk with the cult member, you will start to receive missions from Epsom (something like a **£**).

Comment: I had finished the game and and when i looked i found it

Comment: Ok, so in what point of the quest are you right now?

Comment: entered the Epsom site

Comment: I will edit the answer then